# DoCmd.BrowseTo acBrowseToForm, error object required

Tags: ms-access, vba

I recently created a database for annual QC checks.  I am having trouble creating a front page to view all the information and filter the data using fields as hyperlinks.

**Overall setup:** 
ending if F: form
ending in Q: query
ending in T: table

`MapF` contains: `RegionF`(in empty cell), `FacilityF`(in subform: contain_facility).

I am trying to click on the `regionID`(autogenerated primary key) and have `faciltyF` filter the data to only show the associated facilities.  They are related in a 1 to many relationship, as in one region can have multiple facilities.

**VBA Code:**

```vb
Private Sub IDregion_Click()
MsgBox "[region] = '" & Me.IDregion & "'"
DoCmd.BrowseTo acBrowseToForm, "facilityF", MapF.contain_facility, "[region] = '" & Me.IDregion & "'", , acFormReadOnly
End Sub
```

When I click the link on `MapF`, I get the popup saying `[region]='1'` after clicking ok, I get the error message:

> run-time error'424': object required

Any help you could offer would be great.

Comment: Is `MapF` a navigation form?  If so is `contain_facility` a navigation subform?

Comment: If IDregion is a number, you don't need the single quotes. You're telling to see the 1 as a string instead of a number.

Comment: @Gene I think that is part of the issue, but the error he is getting doesn't really match that part of the code I don't think.

Comment: @newd - absolutely correct, that's why i didn't post it as an answer.

Comment: @Newd nope, its just a blank form, with added subforms in a cell.  I couldnt get the path right without a subform.

Comment: @Gene oh, that makes sense. Thank you, i will make the change.

Answer (score 0):

As per the information found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196381.aspx), the `PathtoSubformControl` parameter is a string.  So your code should look more like this:

```vb
Private Sub IDregion_Click()
    DoCmd.BrowseTo acBrowseToForm, "facilityF", "MapF.contain_facility", "[region] = " & Me.IDregion , , acFormReadOnly
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for your response.  I ended up just using a macro to do it as i had a deadline.